# Google map suddenly stopped working (coming up blank)

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I have an asp.net webpage which gets geo data from a REST API. I am parsing the JSON, pulling values out and putting them as markers on the map. The control was working fine until a few days ago, when it just stopped working.

Instead of the map, that section of the page is just blank. I know the service is returning data because I am displaying it on a grid. If I comment out the adding marker part, I do get a map (without the markers / overlays, of course).

I have looked around for hours, tinkered with code, but nothing seems to be working. I even upgraded to the newer version of the Reimers control on my local machine, but still nothing..Any pointers or help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the code...

```
    Reimers.Google.Map.Marker[] markers = new Reimers.Google.Map.Marker[result.Count];

    var centerLatLng = new Reimers.Google.Map.LatLng();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    {
        centerLatLng.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(result[i]["geolatitude"].ToString());
        centerLatLng.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(result[i]["geolongitude"].ToString());
        markers[i] = new Reimers.Google.Map.Marker(centerLatLng);

        markers[i].Title = result[i]["fullName"].ToString() + " - " + result[i]["callType"].ToString() + " : " + result[i]["comments"];
        markers[i].Description = result[i]["callType"].ToString();

        Map1.Overlays.Add(markers[i]);
    }

    Map1.Center = centerLatLng;
    Map1.Zoom = 4;
```

Comment: This is my control. It sounds like you are getting a JavaScript error on the page. Can you check that and post any information about this?

Answer (score 0):

@jjrdk: Thanks for your help, I really like the control.

After much investigation, I found that a particular record was throwing the control off. Honestly, I do not know what about that record broke the code, but it just did not like it.

I even copied the data from the bad record to another one, and the code worked. From what I can tell, the data in the bad record had some international characters, which were probably not working with the overlay / map, and it kept on giving an uncaught exception JavaScript error.

After I deleted that record, the code started working fine again. Not optimal, but I am glad it works. I will probably add more client validation to ensure that it works.

Thanks!